# Xero webhooks with Node Red; OK, than not ok

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red, xero-api

I have been dealing with cryptography craziness since yesterday, I 've literally lost my sleep over this.

I am implementing a node red solution to get webhooks from Xero to be written in a custom app. I have experienced a lot of issues with the payload and how it needs to be stringified and how needs to be hashed, but eventually figured it out thanks to a Github fellow that posted this code to get the body to its 'raw' state

`let msgPayloadRaw = JSON.stringify(msg.payload).split(':').join(': ').split(': [').join(':[').split(',"entropy"').join(', "entropy"');`

I then create a sha256 base64 hash to check against the header value using the following js code

```
var cryptojs = context.global.cryptojs;

const webhookKey = 'MyWebhookKeyHere';

let msgPayloadRaw = JSON.stringify(msg.payload).split(':').join(': ').split(': [').join(':[').split(',"entropy"').join(', "entropy"');


let bdata = new Buffer(msgPayloadRaw).toString();

let ciphertext = cryptojs.HmacSHA256(bdata, webhookKey );

let base64encoded = cryptojs.enc.Base64.stringify(ciphertext);


msg.payload = base64encoded;

return msg;
```

Now everything should work great, but I get a crazy result showcased in [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4qivll6nv6hedaj/XeroWebhook.mp4?dl=0) recording, where the web hooks intent status turns to 'OK', and some seconds later returns to this error:

```
Retry
We haven’t received a successful response on the most recent delivery attempt and will retry sending with decreasing frequency for an overall period of 24 hours.
Response not 200. Learn more
Last sent at 2022-06-22 11:48:28 UTC
```

## What's the problem ?

The problem relies in the http input, where node red parsed the body.

Body needs to be hashed. The body in the http request is like that

```
{"events":[],"firstEventSequence": 0,"lastEventSequence": 0, "entropy": "IVMMHNWPBAZYRZJRCUAQ"}
```

Notice the spaces after each :

Node Red converts that body to JSON object. When I do `JSON.stringify(msg.payload);` I will get the following

`{"events":[],"firstEventSequence":0,"lastEventSequence":0, "entropy":"IVMMHNWPBAZYRZJRCUAQ"}`

which is obviously the same, but technically it is not (due to spaces) and when hashed it generates a different hash value.

The GitHub fellow did that that walkround

```
JSON.stringify(msg.payload).split(':').join(': ').split(': [').join(':[').split(',"entropy"').join(', "entropy"');
```

So in order to solve this, I need to find a way to get the raw http input, instead of the parsed one that node red is providing.

Any ideas how to get the raw input ?

Comment: Please properly explain what the problem is, directly within the question - instead of sending us to external resources to watch videos ...

Comment: The webhook temporarily turns to 'OK', and after a couple of seconds returns to Retry
We haven’t received a successful response on the most recent delivery attempt and will retry sending with decreasing frequency for an overall period of 24 hours.
Response not 200. Learn more
Last sent at 2022-06-22 11:48:28 UTC

Comment: Updated the description as well, kept the external video recording to my personal Dropbox, where I am showcasing how this error occurs in Xero developer platform

Comment: @CBroe I don't get what you don't understand. The question is straightforward. The link is just an additional aid to better explain what the issue is.

Comment: _"The question is straightforward"_ - as is, what the error message told you. We can't possible tell you what prevented your endpoint from properly responding with 200 OK - you are the one with access to the system, so you will have to do some debugging.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @CBroe How about now ? > How to get raw http in in Node Red ? The only problem with that is that I am constraining the problem to 1 solution, where the problem is I cannot verify the hash due to automated node red body parsing

Comment: I had the same issue using a no-code tool which is why this solution from Xero is not ideal. In the end I got around it by using ngrok + postman so that I could inspect the exact body structure and then used it as a string template: `const intentBodyTemplate = \`{"events":[],"firstEventSequence": 0,"lastEventSequence": 0, "entropy": "${body.entropy}"}\`;`. This way the spaces e.g. between `": 0` are presered in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Sort answer: you don't.

The raw body is not available if the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json` the bodyParser will kick in and generate the matching JSON object that is passed as the msg.payload.

the `httpNodeMiddleware` is attached after the bodyParser so the body has already been changed.